# Bash script with pipe can not working as expceted in crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron, grep

start.sh

```sh
PID=`ps -ef | grep 'anticheat' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2;}'`
if [ ! -z "$PID" ]; then
    echo "PID FOUNDED :" $PID
    echo "IF YOU WANNA TO RESTART, PLEASE USE THE RESTART SCRIPT"
    exit
else
    # start service
    if [ -z "$PID" ]; then
        echo "START SERVER ERROR"
        exit
    else
        echo "START SERVER SUCCESSFULLY"
    fi
fi
```

output for commend line

```
++ pwd
+ cur_dir=/search/odin/online/anticheat
+ anticheat_bin=anticheat
++ ps -ef
++ grep anticheat
++ grep -v grep
++ awk '{print $2;}'
+ PID=17821
+ '[' '!' -z 17821 ']'
+ echo 'PID FOUNDED :' 17821
PID FOUNDED : 17821
+ echo 'IF YOU WANNA TO RESTART, PLEASE USE THE RESTART SCRIPT'
IF YOU WANNA TO RESTART, PLEASE USE THE RESTART SCRIPT
+ exit
```

it can work rightly when I run a bash shell in commend line, however it doesn't work as expected in crontab.

```
++ grep anticheat
++ grep -v grep
++ ps -ef
++ awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'
+ PID='17821
23184'
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: It's finding two processes matching 'anticheat'; you'll have to investigate to find out what they are. Maybe remove the `awk` step, so you can see the entire relevant output from `ps`? Also, if it's available `pgrep` is almost always better for things like this.

Comment: Also consider writing a service for your RC instead.

Comment: Thanks for you@GordonDavisson. `pgrep` works well. I'm still wonder why `grep` can work well by manual and it works wrong in cron.

Comment: To find out, why it does not work in cron, I suggest that you output the result of your `grep -v` for further investigation.

Comment: Not sure it work anywhere, `grep 'anticheat'` will always return at least one PID. You need to work around it using `grep '[a]nticheat'`

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. `grep 'anticheat' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2;}'` = `awk '/anticheat/ && !/grep/ {print $2}'` which since you're now using awk instead of grep you'd really want to be `awk '/anticheat/ && !/awk/{print $2}'` but that's all the wrong way to do this anyway as @GordonDavisson and Wiktor pointed out.